# How to create email accounts with PHP and sendmail/SMTP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to create email accounts for a specific domain with PHP and sendmail/SMTP?

Comment: This is not answerable in the current form.  We'd need to know what mail server software you're using before answering... and even then, you'd find the answer in the documentation for that software.

Comment: In that case 90% of stackoverflow answers can be found in documentations.  Plus i already specified sendmail.

Comment: sendmail is not a mail server.  It routes email TO mail servers.  It is a mail sender, if you will.  It sends mail, and was therefore creatively named sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the server you are running - if you are using XAMPP, you can start the Mercury-Server and configure it as you want.